# how pointer assignment and increment is working in below example

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning the pointers in C. I am little confused about how below program is working

```
int main()
{
    int x=30, *y, *z;
    y=&x; 
    z=y;
    *y++=*z++;
    x++;
    printf("x=%d, y=%p, z=%p\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
x=31, y=0x7ffd6c3e1e70, z=0x7ffd6c3e1e70
```

`y` and `z` are pointing to the next integer address of variable `x`.
I am not able to understand how this line is working

```
*y++=*z++;
```

can someone please explain me how this one line is understood by C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*y++=*z++;` actually means

```
*y = *z;
y += 1*(sizeof(int)); //because int pointers are incremented by 4bytes each time
z += 1*(sizeof(int)); //because int pointers are incremented by 4bytes each time
```

So pointed value does not affected, pointers are incremented by one.

Comment: Except that the order of sub-operations is not predetermined.

Comment: @pmg you are right, do you have any example about that situation. I like to read about that.

Comment: @pgm: I'm note sure that matters: the compiler may well reorder the final two statements anyway.

Comment: I can't think of an example that doesn't attempt to read and write to an object without an intervening sequence point: `*z = *z++;`

Comment: Suppose y and z are I/O ports and declared as `volatile`. y activates a chip select and needs to be set before z sends a signal through that chip. If y is sequenced before z, everything will work fine. If z is sequenced before y, nothing will happen.

Comment: @Lundin Nice explenation.